# How to use javascript via youtube v3 api upload video

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-javascript-api

I'm currently using the form data method to upload a video to youtube api, but I have been receiving the following respond error

> "message": "Uploads must be sent to the upload URL. Re-send this request to https://www.googleapis.com/upload/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet,statistics,contentDetails&mine=true&access_token=ya29.ImGUB0a_t9jFeGl1jxduJWSr6qgOKtzb7UpJNMxjyX-U7tkwCTvBx1nEMWunodpyKoULnQqfBkxgzxvs1S27_LTPRIqkTokWHh7quTMssHpRGRpaQiCJzGxKV3wxWjypqQMk"

Youtube v3 API [link](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert)

The following is my request

```
Request URL: https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet,statistics,contentDetails&mine=true&access_token=ya29.ImGUB0a_t9jFeGl1jxduJWSr6qgOKtzb7UpJNMxjyX-U7tkwCTvBx1nEMWunodpyKoULnQqfBkxgzxvs1S27_LTPRIqkTokWHh7quTMssHpRGRpaQiCJzGxKV3wxWjypqQMk
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 400 

Request Headers:

Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryFpMCekYXv6NAPEKN
Origin: http://localhost:8080
Referer: http://localhost:8080/
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.90 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest

Query string:

part: snippet,statistics,contentDetails
mine: true
access_token: ya29.ImGUB0a_t9jFeGl1jxduJWSr6qgOKtzb7UpJNMxjyX-U7tkwCTvBx1nEMWunodpyKoULnQqfBkxgzxvs1S27_LTPRIqkTokWHh7quTMssHpRGRpaQiCJzGxKV3wxWjypqQMk
```

Can someone tell me what went wrong? very thankful.